# osg's official packed depth stencil example doesn't work as expected

Tags: opengl, openscenegraph

I'm learning from the example of osgpackeddepthstencil of OSG. This example first renders a mask square into a RTTI camera, affacting the stencil buffer while leaving the color buffer untouched. The stencil test is:

```
osg::Stencil *stencil = new osg::Stencil;
stencil->setFunction(osg::Stencil::ALWAYS, 1, ~0u);
stencil->setOperation(osg::Stencil::KEEP, osg::Stencil::KEEP, osg::Stencil::REPLACE);
osg::StateSet *ss = geode->getOrCreateStateSet();
ss->setAttributeAndModes(stencil, osg::StateAttribute::ON|osg::StateAttribute::OVERRIDE);
ss->setAttribute(new osg::ColorMask(false, false, false, false),osg::StateAttribute::ON|osg::StateAttribute::OVERRIDE);
```

Then it renders a larger square into the same RTTI camera, setting the stencil test as not equal to 1. Then use the texture to render a square. The second stencil test codes are below:

```
osg::Stencil *stencil = new osg::Stencil;
stencil->setFunction(osg::Stencil::NOTEQUAL, 1, ~0u);
stencil->setOperation(osg::Stencil::KEEP, osg::Stencil::KEEP, osg::Stencil::KEEP);
osg::StateSet *ss = geode->getOrCreateStateSet();
ss->setAttributeAndModes(stencil, osg::StateAttribute::ON|osg::StateAttribute::OVERRIDE);
```

Everything goes fine, and the result is shown below. The clear color is green. The center of the square is green since the stencil buffer values are 1 in this small square due to the first round of rendering.

[image]

However, question comes when I change the second stencil test to be not equal to 0. According to my knowledge of stencil test, the result should be a reversed image of the previous one, which has a green boundary and a grey inner square. Quite confusing, the result is as follows which is a whole green:

[image]

What am I missing? How to interpret the second result? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks! My OSG version is 3.4.0. My environment is : NVIDIA GTX 750 TI, Windows 10 64bit, Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: "I change the second stencil test to be not equal to 0" please show that part of the code.

Comment: The second stencil test is the second piece of code shown above. So it's almost the same as the second piece of code, the only difference lies in the line of setFunction with the number 1 changing to be 0.